# How can i change included xml layout to another layout on java code?

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

I included second layout to first layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:id="@+id/rlMenu"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMusteriler"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Musteriler"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rlEkranlar"
     >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/ikinci" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem is how can I change included layout when clicked a button(on java code)?

Comment: create a new xml file and activity and call second through intent.

Comment: please modify your question, its not much clear.

Comment: @YugandharBabu I want to change layout="@layout/ikinci" to layout="@layout/third_layout" when clicked the button.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I suggest `ViewFlipper` inside `RelativeLayout` of your `include` statements. Try like this:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vf"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <include android:id="@+id/include1" layout="@layout/ikinci" />
    <include android:id="@+id/map" layout="@layout/third_layout" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Access ViewFlipper as below.
Initially first layout is output:

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.vf);
```

For Button onClickListener:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vf.setDisplayedChild(1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
You fixed the problem =))

Comment: For experience, if use ViewFlipper maybe you can see a little slow in your app....

Answer (score 24):

There is two ways to change layouts in code:

A. Change visibility. Include tow different layouts in your xml:

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
<include 
    android:id="@+id/id2"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

and in code use this:

```
findViewById(R.id.id1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.id2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

B. Manually add children. Use the same xml as you use now and add in code you can add or delete children:

```
yourRelativeLayout.removeAllViews();
yourRelativeLayout.addView(viewToInclude);
```

Offtopic:

You don't need to write `xmlns:android` param in RelativeLayout. Just for the most top tag in  layout file.

Comment: I was confused because Intellij 14 does not offer "visibility" in autocomplete options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the instance of the current view of the xml you have included the other xml and use `findViewById()`. View v is the first layout and against this view you use `.findViewById()`

Comment: i tried this: 
Layout L1 = (Layout) findViewById (R.id.layout1); 
There is convert error. Can't convert View to Layout. 
Am i doing wrong somethings?

Comment: Layout? There is no such View in SDK as long as you created your own. Make sure you referenced the class names properly. Like: LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout....

Comment: i tried you suggestion.  
But i cant solve my problem. I want change included layout when a button clicked. I can't found a method for this. How can i do that?  
Thanks.